# New to AC to DC conversion!

Tags: voltage, batteries, ac, dc, electricity

I'm new to this forum, so apologies if I am posting this in the wrong place. I am looking to start a DIY project, and this entails electricity and water; I know, two things that  **shouldn't ever**  be near each other! However, I want a device that is plugged into an outlet, can spin water around (almost like a dishwasher arm). I made a basic checklist for the electrical components: I need a motor, a few fans, wires, and an AC to DC converter. I did some preliminary research and found that a BLDC motor would suit me best (little to no maintenance). I chose DC because I need multiple devices (the motor and the fans) to run on either 120V-240V AC current (plugged into the wall). What is your take on this. I by no means have a degree in mechanical/electrical engineering (I'm still in HS). Would it just be better to simply use separate lithium-ion batteries (Duracell, for example) per device (one battery for each fan, and motor), or is what I'm suggesting feasible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Opinion based answers are generally not what this site is about so, ask a specific question is my strong advice. This is, after all, a Q and A site.

Comment: Most likely you don't need a motor. Dishwasher arms don't use one. They use reaction force from expelled water, just like a rocket. Look how a rotary sprinkler is made. Since you will have a pump anyway, you can probably get rid of the extra motor.

Comment: "Trolling motor"?